# Font Size does not work for tabs : DocuSign

Tags: c#, asp.net, docusignapi

I am using embedded DocuSign in my project. I need to set the size of initials as small as possible. I known that Size7 is the least size, which I can set. But some how it is not working in my case. Even if I change the FontSize to Size24 it doesn't reflect. I guess I am missing something. 
I have also added the code below.

```
List<Tab> eipTabs = new List<Tab>();
Tab signHere = new Tab();
signHere.Type = TabTypeCode.InitialHere;
signHere.Name = "Sign Here";
signHere.TabLabel = "CustomerSignature";
signHere.DocumentID = documentId;
signHere.RecipientID = recipientId;
signHere.PageNumber = "20";
signHere.XPosition = "50";
signHere.YPosition = "170";
signHere.FontSize = FontSize.Size7;
signHere.FontSizeSpecified = true;
eipTabs.Add(signHere);
```

Can anyone help me on how to go about on this?

Comment: Just curious, do is make any difference if you set it to a string value instead?  Like `signHere.FontSize = "5";`?

Comment: Hi @Ergin, it won't work since this property on excepts value of type "FontSize". Here FontSize is an enum with all possible values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code sample, it looks like you're adding an "Initial Here" tab.  If that's correct, then the reason that setting the **FontSize** property isn't having any effect is that **FontSize** is not a valid property for an "Initial Here" tab.

If you're using the REST API, you'll want to use the **scaleValue** property to control the size of the "Initial Here" tab.  Here's the property definition from the [DocuSign REST API Guide](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf):

[image: property description]

So, try specifying the **scaleValue** property in your request (instead of specifying **FontSize**), and that should allow you to control the size of the "Initial Here" tab.

If you're using the SOAP API, you'll want to use the **ScaleValue** property to control the size of the "Initial Here" tab. Here's the property definition from the [WSDL](https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/schema/dsapi.wsdl):

[image: WSDL]

And the property description from the [SOAP API Guide](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSignAPI_Guide.pdf):

[image: SOAP Property Desc]

Also, make sure that you're setting the corresponding *specified* property -- and perhaps try using lowercase **m** after the decimal (rather than uppercase).  So, it would look something like this:

```
signHere.ScaleValue = .50m;
signHere.ScaleValueSpecified = true;
```

Comment: Hi Kim thanks for the reply. I tried your solution but it didn't worked. I am not using REST API, which should not be a problem.

    I replaced signHere.FontSize = FontSize.Size7; with signHere.ScaleValue = 0.5M. It doesn't seem to work. Is there anything else that also needs to changed.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include information about using the SOAP API. Be sure to set the ScaleValueSpecified property -- without it, the ScaleValue property won't be included in the XML request payload.